# inserting string in stack using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

i am confused with the code below. why does the input overwrite the elements in the stack.

for example i enter "abc" first
then the stack will be "123"
but when i enter another string, let's say "234"
the stack will be "234" "234"

but when i used int data type instead of char for my input, there's no error.

thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node{
    char* info;
    struct node *ptr;
}*top,*top1,*temp;

int count = 0;

/* Push data into stack */
void pushy(char* data){
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        top->ptr = NULL;
        strcpy(top->info, data);
    }
    else
    {
        temp =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        temp->ptr = top;
        strcpy(temp->info, data);
        top = temp;
    }
    count++;
 }

/* Display stack elements */
void display(){
    top1 = top;

    if (top1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        return;
    }

    while (top1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", top1->info);
        top1 = top1->ptr;
    }
 }

/* Pop Operation on stack */
void pop(){
    top1 = top;

    if (top1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Trying to pop from empty stack");
        return;
    }
    else
        top1 = top1->ptr;
    printf("\n Popped value : %s", top->info);
    free(top);
    top = top1;
    count--;
}

/* Return top element */
char* topelement(){
    return(top->info);
}

int main()
{
    int ch=0;


    printf("\n 1 - Push");
    printf("\n 2 - Pop");
    printf("\n 3 - Top");
    printf("\n 4 - Display");
    printf("\n 5 - Exit");

    top = NULL;

    while (1)
    {
        char no[10]={NULL};
        char* e;

        printf("\n Enter choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        if(ch==1){
            printf("Enter data : ");
            scanf("\n\n%s", &no);
            pushy(no);
        }
        else if(ch==2){
            pop();
        }
        else if(ch==3){
            if (top == NULL)
                printf("No elements in stack");
            else
            {
                e = topelement();
                printf("\n Top element : %d", e);
            }
        }
        else if(ch==4)
            display();            
        else if(ch==5)
            exit(0);
        else
             printf("Invalid");
   }
}
```

Comment: Quick glance: you do not allocate memory for `info` member of `struct node`, so probably all the `info`s are pointing to the same memory location. Normally you would have a segmentation fault. Change `strcpy` to `strdup`, to automatically allocate memory and create a copy of the string. Also don't forget to free `top->info` just before `free(top)` in `pop` function.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least function `pushy` has undefined behaviour beacuse it tries to overwrite memory that was not allocated by the function

```
void pushy(char* data){

    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        top->ptr = NULL;
        strcpy(top->info, data);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    }
    //...
```

You should at first allocate memory that will be pointed to by data member `top->info` where you are going to copy the string pointed to by parameter `data`

For example

```
void pushy(char* data){

    if (top == NULL)
    {
        top =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        top->ptr = NULL;
        top->info = malloc( ( strlen( data ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
        strcpy(top->info, data);
    }
    //...
```

The function could be written the following way

```
void pushy( const char* data )
{
    temp = ( struct node * )malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    temp->ptr = top;
    temp->info = ( char * )malloc( ( strlen( data ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( temp->info, data );

    top = temp;
    ++count;
}
```

Of cpurse you have to free also the memory allocated for `top->info` when you will free the node itself in function `pop()`.
Take into account that there is no need to declare variables `top1` and `temp` like global.

Also in this call

```
scanf("\n\n%s", &no);
```

the second argument shall be specified simply like `no` instead of `&no`

And in this call

```
printf("\n Top element : %d", e);
```

you have to use format specifier `%s` instead of `%d`

Comment: @oreopeppermint What do you mean?

Comment: you said that the function pushy could be written like in the 3rd code. so i changed the function pushy to that code. am i getting you wrong?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 3rd example `top->info = ( char * )malloc( ( strlen( data ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( top->info, data );` : `top` should be `temp`. its typo.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Thanks. It was a typo due to "copy and paste".:)

Comment: @oreopeppermint See my post with the updated function definition.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("\n\n%s", &no);
```

Remove '&' from the above statement.

Also, as per you code better to take info as `char array` instead of `char *`

```
struct node{
    char info[20];
    struct node *ptr;
}*top,*top1,*temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

No memory is being allocated for the string in the node:

```
top =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
top->ptr = NULL;
strcpy(top->info, data);
```

When strcpy is called top->info pointer is invalid. You will have to allocate the memory, assing it to the pointer top->info and then copy the string into that memory.

Don't forget to free the memory held my info pointer before you free the entire node.